# Retrieve certificate using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to retrieve a certificate using OpenSSL.

The DNS of a certain URL returns two mail servers:

mx00.ionos.de and mx01.ionos.de

Port 25 and SMTP are available!

```
openssl s_client -connect mx01.ionos.de:25 -starttls smtp
```

Response: "Didn't find STARTTLS..."

However, the online tool on this website can extract the certificate:

https://www.secumail.de/mailserveranalyse/

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this using OpenSSL or nmap?

Thanks for your help!

```
openssl s_client -connect mx01.ionos.de:25 -starttls smtp
```